# In Magento ,is it possible to modify the default template files via custom modules without hacking into its *.phtml core files?

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento

I am creating a custom module where i added a button in product view page(default file).I have inserted the button code in the following file

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml
```

and the button gets displayed & works well.But everytime Magento is updated , the above file gets replaced and so my code is discarded.Is there any way to modify or extend or inject the template coding from within my custom module?Should i need to override the core blocks or somehting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Give your module a layout file:

  ```
  ...
  <frontend>
      <layout>
          <updates>
              <YOUR_MODULE>
                  <file>YOURMODULE.xml</file>
              </YOUR_MODULE>
          </updates>
      </layout>
  </frontend>
  ...
  ```
- In the base theme's `layout/YOURMODULE.xml` file:

  ```
  <layout version="1.0">
      <catalog_product_view>
          <reference name="product.info">
              <action method="setTemplate"><name>YOURMODULE/product/view.phtml</name></action>
          </reference>
      </catalog_product_view>
  </layout>
  ```
- Copy the modified `view.phtml` to a new directory, `template/YOURMODULE/product/`
- When packaging your module remember to include all these files but don't overwrite `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.

Anyone downloading your module might want to make their own changes to that template so you should also include instructions on which file has been changed and where to find it. Since `view.phtml` is often changed by both themers and other modules it would be a much better idea to alter one of the child templates instead - which one depends on where your button will be.

As a bonus there is a block called `extrahint` just after the prices of type `core/text_list` - it doesn't have a template so you might normally miss it when using [template path hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/). You can safely add as many templates as you like to it without altering any existing ones:

```
<layout version="1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.extrahint">
            <block type="core/template" name="YOUR.CUSTOM.BLOCK" template="YOUR/CUSTOM/TEMPLATE.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

That only helps if just after the price is useful for you. Other blocks that can be safely appended are the options and containers areas, but they only show for products with options.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.One doubt,The reference name tag that you mentioned ` <reference name="product.info"> ` is used to refer any particular block , part of default view.phtml or just for our reference?Also which layout xml file deals with product view.phtml page?

Comment: `product.info` refers specifically to the `catalog/product_view` block  which displays the `view.phtml` template. Search the file `catalog.xml` to see where and how it is used, and for the names of other blocks used on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are installing it in app/design/frontend/base/default.

You need to create a copy of this directory in another directory, such as  app/design/frontend/default/yoursite.

[Read this for more info on how to do it specifically](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes)

Comment: that's not really a practical solution if the custom module is to be installed by other users... you can't ask them to change their design just for your module

Comment: actually this is the magento way to do it and if custom functionality is installed templates can be modified or replaced  by your pre modified template. We can't access every dom element through layout files and theoretically we can pre-parse the template and always replace inside of it but that's not cool and only makes the designer life harder

Comment: @Anton S: Yes,even if it possible to access every dom element ,it leads to more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't build your custom extension to be dependent on default views it shows bad planning. you should either clone this template or extend it and have ways to enable and disable your functionality. The must have thing is "designers guide" if your module implements templates or has ways to modify other templates.